# LocalDb connection : Login failed

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, ef-code-first

In a 4.0 winforms application (build on Win2008/VS2012/ ClickOnce), I'm using a LocalDB database with Entity Framework 5 Code First (including database initialization, no migration)

Sometimes, after a build/publish, the application can't connect to the database ( located in the default path of c:\Admin[WindowsAccountName]) : when debugging from Visual Studio, or on customer computer. The exception is System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException, "login failed", in TryGetConnection.

I can fix it if :

1. I delete the database files (r-ecreated by EF)
2. I change the database name in the connection string (again, the db is re-created)
3. I zipped the database files (to keep a bakcup), deleted them (to check solution 1), then unzipped them in the same location, and it worked (weird, but true)
4. on a fresh computer, there's no problem

My connection string is :

```
<add name="SupplyChainContext" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
connectionString="Server=(localdb)\v11.0;Database=MySupplyChainDb;
Trusted_Connection=true;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"/>
```

It happened yesterday again, and the code changes I made have nothing to do with the database : the CodeFirst objects were not changed, the only thing related i can think is that I removed an user settings in app.config (non database related)

It reminds me of the dark days of visual basic deployment, when you were never sure an installation were going to work